# SQL Server Update statement to change year and month of a datetime column

Tags: sql-server

I want to update the `TimeOccurred` column in all tables in a database (also fine with doing 1 table at a time if that is necessary). This is what the current values in this column look like:

```
2017-06-12 14:34:00
```

I would like to replace that value in all tables in the column `TimeOccurred` by changing just the year to the current year and the month to the previous month.

So `2012-03-14 14:34:00` becomes `2017-05-14 14:34:00`.

It would also help if I could check the day and if it was 29,30,or 31 change it to 25.

**Update**:

It's -1 month based on the current right now month. We want to change the days in case the month ends up being February, we can't have an event happening on February 31st for example. So all events should be days 1-28 to be safe.

**More sample data**:

```
2014-07-28 13:03:00
2012-07-28 13:03:00
2015-07-28 13:03:00
2014-07-28 13:03:00
2015-07-28 13:03:00
2016-07-29 11:02:00
2013-07-29 11:07:00
2005-07-29 11:12:00
2010-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
2015-07-29 14:37:00
```

Comment: 3 is not the previous month of 5

Comment: How did you get that sample output based on your rules?

Comment: @Sami It's currently June. Previous month is May. I am curious he wants the day to be 25 instead of 28.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Well , we can't say or guess until the Q updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, just replace `your_table_name` with each table you want to apply this to.

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET TimeOccurred = 
    CAST( CAST( DATEPART( YEAR, GETDATE() ) AS VARCHAR( 4 ) ) + '-' +
         CAST( DATEPART( MONTH, DATEADD( MONTH, -1, GETDATE() ) ) AS VARCHAR( 2 ) ) + '-' + 
         (CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART( DAY, TimeOccurred ) IN ( 29, 30, 31 ) 
            THEN '25'
            ELSE CAST( DATEPART( DAY, TimeOccurred ) AS VARCHAR( 2 ) )
         END) +
         RIGHT( TimeOccurred, 8 )
     AS SMALLDATETIME )
```

**Output**:

```
+---------------------+
|    TimeOccurred     |
+---------------------+
| 2017-05-28 13:03:00 |
| 2017-05-28 13:03:00 |
| 2017-05-28 13:03:00 |
| 2017-05-28 13:03:00 |
| 2017-05-28 13:03:00 |
| 2017-05-25 11:02:00 |
| 2017-05-25 11:07:00 |
| 2017-05-25 11:12:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
| 2017-05-25 14:37:00 |
+---------------------+
```

**Demo:**
[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ZXY21763)

Comment: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Could you edit your question with some more sample data? This works for me based on the sample you gave, see the demo.

Comment: Added sample data, each data/time is a separate row/event in the table.

Comment: Could you look at the demo at the bottom of my answer, it still runs fine with that input.

Comment: Is it going to reformat my whole date time column to yyyy.mm.dd instead of yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: No, it will keep it in the same format. Look at the output in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I decided to backup my DB and try your solution and it appears to have worked.

Comment: Would it be extremely difficult to make this so it only applied to the rows I've already selected instead of an entire table?

Comment: Depends what you mean by that, I'm assuming you mean don't update the row if the date has already been updated before?

Comment: I just meant being able to add a select statement to it so I could say something like "only update the date if column X contains value Y".  After looking at it more, I'm not sure this is actually necessary, I appreciate all the time/help you've given.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, TimeOccurred, current_timestamp)-1, TimeOccurred)
```

See this to prove it works, including a demo for what will happen at the end of March rolling into February:

> http://rextester.com/TIATZ28074

Comment: Joel this looks very good.  Would it be difficult to maintain the same format?  2017-05-31 instead of 2017.05.31?

Comment: Dates don't have formats. That's a displaying feature.

Comment: @B.Breckenridge Hey, my original didn't always work for some dates not in your sample data... especially when crossing year boundaries. Updated version is better. I was trying to be too clever using year * 12 for the diff value rather than just month.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET TimeOccurred = DATEADD(MM, -1, TimeOccurred)
```

Comment: This did work for changing the month, but there is a lot more to it for me to be finished with this requirement.  I appreciate your help though, one step closer.

Comment: @B.Breckenridge mark the question as the answer if it helped